# Column border invisible

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table using divs. The structure of the table with two columns is something like

```
<div>
<div class = "columnborder"><span>Some text for column 1</span></div>
<div><span>Some text for column 2</span></div>
</div>
```

I want columns with a vertical border in between. So gave a class 'columnborder' to the div representing a table cell as

```
.columnborder{
  border-right  :1px black;
}
```

This works pretty well and I got the expected behavior of a table with two columns separated by a vertical border in between. But when the first column text is empty, the span is not created. The structure will be something like

```
<div>
 <div class = "columnborder"></div>
 <div><span>Some text for column 2</span></div>
</div>
```

In that case, the border doesn't show up. I wouldnt expect this to happen as I have applied the style to the div not the span. How can I avoid this scenario? What could be causing this?

Comment: Give width to the `div`

Comment: Does your left column div has a minimum width? You should post the full CSS in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Note: You arent closing your `div` tag, also `border-right :1px black;` is invalid as it stands above. it should be `border-right  :1px solid;`

Comment: You can also try filing empty `div` with `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @SW4 shouldn't it be `border-right: 1px solid black;`?

Comment: @ThePragmatick - items are not mandatory (note, default color is black), ordering is important though- `width style color`, so you shouldnt do, e.g. `width color`, as `color` will be interpreted as a `style` so both are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS:

As SW4 said, your statement is invalid. It should be:

```
.columnborder{border-right:1px solid;}
```

and close div tags :

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="columnborder"></div> /* close div */
    <div><span>Some text for column 2</span></div> /* close div */
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div's are not closed check your structure and close the div's

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/9w13gkkg/)

```
<div>
    <div class = "columnborder"><span>Some text for column 1</span></div>
    <div><span>Some text for column 2</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.columnborder{
  border-right  :1px solid black;
  width:160px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I's suggest to use `flexbox`. The border will be always in table height, not depending in cell height. This is because `flexbox` items have by default `align-items: stretch` (stretch to fill the container).

```css
.table {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.table > div {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}
.table > div:first-of-type {
  border-right: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <span>Some text for column 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text for column 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should declare

```
.columnborder { display:table-cell; border-right:1px solid black; }
```

now empty div has 0 height, so no border is displayed. You may also use `min-height: 1.5em;` property to set minimum height for empty div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be reduced to the following case:

```html
<style>
div {
  width: 5em;
}
.columnborder{
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}
</style>
<div class = "columnborder">something</div>
<div class = "columnborder"></div>
```

So there is no right border for the second `div`.

I have set a fixed width and used a thick red border for clarity. These modifications are not essential to the problem. But the code `border-right  :1px black;` does not work as such, since it sets the border style to `none`, the initial value. Perhaps you are setting it to another value in some part of your CSS code that was not included.

If you inspect the situation using a browser’s Developer Tools, you’ll notice that the height of the second `div` is 0. Therefore, even though it has a right border set, the height of that border is zero, too. The height is zero, since the element has no content.

There are many ways to deal with this. If you use CSS table formatting and the `div` is laid out as a table cell, it will get a nonzero height, according to the tallest cell of the same row—unless of course all other cells of the row lack content, too. You can also explicitly set the height, or you can insert dummy content like a no-break space, which causes an empty line box to be generated. Examples:

```html
<style>
div {
  width: 5em;
}
.columnborder{
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}
</style>
<div class = "columnborder">something</div>
<div class = "columnborder" style="height: 1em"></div>
<div class = "columnborder">&nbsp;</div>
```